# How can I get my Macbook Air 2013 (September 2013) to connect to wi-fi?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, macbook-pro

I just got my new MacBook Air delivered yesterday.  I opened it up today and was happy until it couldn't connect to Wi-Fi.  After Googling I found out that this has been an issue and that Apple created a patch for it.  But that was in July and I got mine yesterday.

Do I have to download that patch even though it's old? I got mine 24 hours ago so I would assume that it would've come with that patch already on it?

I am running 10.8.4.  My ISP is Verizon Fios.

I am confused.  Not sure what to do.  Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong here!

It is correct there are always software updates, but it is not possible that your Airport (WiFi) does not work at all (unless it is broken) and no software will fix that, so you need to send your computer back.

Make sure it is turned on in your system preference - Network- WiFi ON!

Now to the software updates:

Even if you bought it tomorrow does not means it has the latest software updates.

Since you do not have a WiFi Internet connection you can not get the software updates via Internet.

You could bring it back to Apple and they will fix it.

Alternatively, get a piece of Ethernet cable and connect to the router.

Since it is a MBA that does not has a Ethernet plug, you will need a Thunderbolt to Ethernet plug.

Then Click on the Apple (top left) and on the software update.